# Create padded divs side by side

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am making a dice rolling page with 4 dices. I need to get the following result:
[image]

Right now I was able to implement all the logic but I have no idea of how to put each div side by side and add the black padding from the ts code, right now I got:

[image]

As suggested in a comment, I created a parent div and set its display style to inline, but there is no change, here follows my updated code of the Die class that implements each die and the parent div creation:

```
class Die {
    div: Element;
    value: string;
    text: Element;
    numberSides: number = Object.keys(rolledValues).length / 2;

    constructor(parent: HTMLElement, roll: number) {
        let div: Element = document.createElement('div');
        let value = rolledValues[roll];
        let squareSizeNum: number = 20;
        let squareSize: string = `{ $squareSizeNum }px`;
        (<HTMLElement>div).style.width = squareSize;
        (<HTMLElement>div).style.height = squareSize;
        (<HTMLElement>div).style.padding = '3px';
        let text: Element = document.createElement('p');
        text.textContent = value;
        (<HTMLElement>div).appendChild(text);
        parent.appendChild(div);
        this.div = div
        this.text = text;
    }
}

class DieRoller extends Die {
    constructor(parent: HTMLElement, roll: number) {
        super(parent, roll);
    }
    rollDie() {
        let roll: number = this.getRandomIntInclusive(0, this.numberSides - 1)
        this.text.textContent = rolledValues[roll];
    }

    getRandomIntInclusive: Function = (min, max) => {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }
}

let parentDiv: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div')
let numberOfDies: number = 4;
let dies: DieRoller[] = [];
for(let index: number = 0; index < numberOfDies; index++) {
    let dieRoller = new DieRoller(parentDiv, 0);
    dies.push(dieRoller);
    parentDiv.appendChild(dieRoller.div);
}
parentDiv.style.display = 'inline';
document.body.appendChild(parentDiv);
```

Comment: Wrap all the elements in a div and set it's display as inline

Answer (score 0):

You could set the parent/container to use [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Or in your case:

```
parentDiv.style.display = 'flex';
parentDiv.style.justifyContent = 'space-around';
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1zeemv)